# Is this right? (Read in file in C)

Tags: c, file-io

For my assignment I have to create a program similar to the -wc unix command which counts words, lines, etc.

I have to read in flags and read in a text file.

I've set up all the flags and now I'm trying to read in a text file. I don't think I'm doing this right.

```
void readInFile(char** argv, int arg)
{
   FILE *myFile;
   char c;

   myFile = fopen(argv[arg], "r");
   if(!myfile)
   {
      printf("%s not found!", argv[arg]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

in my main I call the function readInFile() and pass 2 arguments. Argv and the element where the file should be. So assume this to be correct.

I need help with actually opening up the file. I feel like my fopen() is wrong. I'm new to reading/writing files in C. Thanks alot!

Comment: I would personally pass in one argument of type `char *`, and do the `argv[x]` in the calling code. Otherwise, it looks OK from what we can see here. Obviously, if this code isn't working, then it's probably some of the code you didn't post [80% of the time, that's the case]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give you some general advice here.

Usually functions should do a single job.  In this case, you are writing a function to read in a single file.  So, don't pass a pointer to all the command-line arguments; pass in a single read-only pointer to the name of the file to open.  Then in `main()` select the correct argument and pass that as the argument.

```
void readInFile(char const *filename)
```

Now, if this function will be reading in the file and doing nothing else, it needs to return the data somehow.  But if this function will be doing the equivalent of `wc`, maybe it will read the file and print stuff, not return any data to the `main()` function.  Then maybe the name should be improved:

```
void wordcount(char const *filename)
```

The actual call to `fopen()` looks fine to me.

You check for error, and then call `exit()` immediately.  That's one way to do it.  Another way to do it is to return an error code from your function, and have the caller (the `main()` function) check for failure, and handle the error there.

```
int wordcount(char const *filename)
{
    // ... do stuff
    if (failed)
        return 1;  // return nonzero error code on failure
    // ... do more stuff
    return 0;  // success code
}

int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
    char const *filename;
    int result;

    filename = argv[1];
    result = wordcount(filename);
    if (result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open file '%s'\n", filename, result);
        exit(result);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

For a program this simple, it doesn't matter much.  But once you start building larger systems in software, you will be happier if your functions work well together, and part of that is making functions that return error codes rather than terminating your whole program on any error.

Why am I using `0` for the success code, and non-zero for failure?  It's a common way to do it.  It's easy to test for non-zero, like `if (result)` and there are many non-zero codes but only one zero, so you can return many different kinds of errors, but there is only one value needed for "success".

Note that instead of calling `exit()` from `main()`, you can just use the `return` statement.  When you return `0` from `main()`, that signals success, and a non-zero value indicates an error.  So you could just use `return result;` from `main()` if you like.

In my dummy code, I'm just returning `1` as the error code.  But actually, when you call `fopen()` it returns an error code to you, in a global variable called `errno`.  Probably a better option is to make your function return the actual error code as specified in `errno`.  You could even modify the print statement in the `main()` function print the `errno` code, or use the `strerror()` function to turn that error code into a human-readable message.

Comment: Thanks for your time on posting a very detailed explanation on how to fix my program. I'll take this into account when I'm cleaning up my code. Right now I just want to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to fopen is correct, assuming that `argv[arg]` is a valid string which refers to a file that exists on the filesystem.

Comment: The valid indices of `argv` are between `0` and `arg - 1`.

Comment: @Code-Guru No, because this is not main. He has already said that `arg` is the *index* into `argv` he wants. The assumption is that `1 <= arg < argc` (where `argc` is what you are actually referring to, and assuming he doesn't want to read the binary into the program). I agree that if this code is not working, that assumption is probably false, but he hasn't posted the surrounding code, and the call to `fopen()` *is* correct.

Comment: Doh! I missed that the function has a different name. My bad. (And it's been too long since my vote, so I can't undo it until your question is edited.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo in the program snippet. if(!myfile) should prpbably be if(!myFile). With this change, I presume the code should work. Can you please elaborate the error faced by you?

P.S: I tried your program and it seems to work!

Comment: Thanks alot. I just don't understand the FILE keyword. I've looked it up and can't seem to grasp it. So does myFile essentially store an array of characters as a "file" type?

Comment: What you get back from the `open()` call is a `FILE *`, a pointer to a `FILE` object.  The `FILE` object is where the C library keeps all the information related to the open file.  You should treat this as a black box, and not try to do anything with it other than pass the pointer to various C library functions like `fread()`.  We usually call this sort of pointer a "handle".  So when you call `fopen()` you get a "file handle" and you can pass this to library functions; then you pass it to `fclose()` to "close the handle" when you are done.

Comment: Ok then I'm doing my program wrong I think. Basically what I'm trying to do is store a file into a variable.. I'm thinking a char array now... and go through every element of the array to find word count, # of characters in the file, # of lines, and longest line in the file.

Comment: @CarlosCarrillo rather than storing the file into a variable, why not iterate through the characters using `fgetc()`? Keep some state variables for whether the last character was part of a word, and how many characters you've seen since the last \n, and you can accumulate all of the statistics you want in running totals.